# Using multiprocessing with google analytics app engine calls with python, pandas

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pandas, google-analytics, multiprocessing

I am attempting to shorten some of the routine requests I make to the google analytics service on the app engine using multiprocessing using the `deco` library (which decorates the multiprocessing library).

I utilise the following code to test things out:

```
import pandas.io.ga as ga
import pandas as pd
from deco import concurrent, synchronized
import time

@concurrent
def d_fetch(date, hour):
        t0 = time.time()
        data[str(date)+'h'+str(hour)] = [
            ga.read_ga(
            account_id  = "xx",
            profile_id  = "xx",
            property_id = "xx",
            metrics     = ['sessions','hits', 'bounces'],
            dimensions  = ['date', 'hour', 'minute', 'medium', 'keyword'],
            start_date  = date,
            end_date    = date,
            index_col = 0,
            filters = "hour==" + '{0:02d}'.format(hour))]
        t1 = time.time()
        data[str(date)+'h'+str(hour)].append(round(t1-t0,2))
        print str(date)+str(hour)+": completed in "+str(round(t1-t0,2))+" secs."

@synchronized
def run(data, dates):
    for date in dates:
        for hour in xrange(24):
            d_fetch(date, hour)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    somemute = {}
    date_range = pd.date_range(start='5/8/2016', end='5/8/2016', freq='D')

    t0 = time.time()
    run(somemute, date_range)
    t1 = time.time()
    print "TOOK", round(t1-t0,2)
```

But I get the following error:

[image]

Is this because the `client_secrets` or `analytics.dat` files gets locked and are unable to be accessed to create tokens? Is there a way to bypass this?

Or is this something that, because it's network heavy and not cpu heavy, should be handled by multi-threaded scripts?

Thanks and sorry again for my naivete.

Comment: Does it work without using `deco`?

Comment: Yes, it runs as expected.

Comment: If you suspect `deco` is the source of the problem might be a good idea to raise an issue at [github](https://github.com/alex-sherman/deco/issues) - developers are responding rather quicly.

Comment: From the `deco` side of things we had suspected there might be some incompatibility with `googleapiclient` and `multiprocessing`. Just brief browsing the documentation, it looks like `oauth2client` supports multiprocessing with locks, but the traceback makes it look like `googleapiclient` maybe throws an exception when it encounters a locked file rather than waiting for it. Has anyone had experience with this before?

Comment: Something I noticed when looking at the `googleapiclient` docs in the multi threading info was that the `httplib2.Http()` objects being passed up the request are not thread safe. i'm not sure this would impact separate processes but i wonder if creating separate `httplib2.Http()` objects for each request might work. i'm going to give it a try this weekend if i can get around to it. thanks for all your help

Comment: re: above see here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/thread_safety#credential-storage-objects-are-thread-safe